# Where can I buy Kotori Habane figurines?

Tags: merchandise, if-my-heart-had-wings

I have no idea where to find Kotori Habane figurines.

Where can I buy them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple search for 羽々音 小鳥 フィギュア on Google shows that there is no official figurine for this character (or any of the other characters from this game). There are trading cards (used good) and dakimakura (which are all sold out), though.

Comment: It is probably worth pointing out that figures are relatively rare merchandise to be produced for an 18+ game, probably because of how quickly the market moves and the amount of investment required to make one. They do exist but much less than for e.g. popular anime. Much more common are things like posters, wall scrolls, dakimakura covers, etc. There are many such items for この大空に、翼をひろげて, and they can be bought (used or sometimes new) from sites like amazon.co.jp, suruga-ya, mandarake, and auctions.yahoo.co.jp.

Comment: @LoganM Ok thanks for pointing out that to me.